# Machine Frame Design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, design, structural-analysis, machine-design

How do I select the cross section for a machine frame? Do I need to refer to the AISC steel construction manual to find the capacity of beams, columns, etc?

Comment: Whjy would your frame be exempt from the regulations ie AISC etc?

Comment: I was just unsure if frames for machines (and not just buildings) were also included. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There are also industry specific references that govern for these types of non-building applications. ASME produces standards for specific types of equipment etc. AISC is not always the conservative one in these situations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For a simple portal frame supporting a mechanism, would I refer to AISC or ASME?